# in Azure API Management, how can I add variables to an incoming request using form-data body before I pass the body to the back-end URL?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, I have an incoming request that passes a multipart/form-data body and I would like to add more variables to the multipart/form-data body before it is sent to the backend URL.

in the Azure APIM Police , I tried deserializing the context.request.body into an object but it did not work.  I also tried to put it into a Jobject and returning the JObject.ToString() and it also did not work.

I have been able to add items to a regular body without issue.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the structure of the request body is a bit more complex than simple JSON
If you want to add more variables to the multipart/form-data body before it is sent to the backend URL, you'll need to manipulate the context.Request.Body property, which contains the raw request body. let me give u a sample snippet for you. as XML

```html
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="newVariable" value="newValue" />
        <set-body>@{
            // Parse the existing multipart/form-data body
            var formData = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.Body.As<string>());

            // Add a new variable
            formData.Add("newVariable", context.Variables["newVariable"].ToString());

            // Reconstruct the multipart/form-data body
            var newBody = string.Join("&", formData.AllKeys.Select(key => $"{key}={formData[key]}"));

            return newBody;
        }</set-body>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I actually tried doing something as simple as putting the context.Request.body into a JObject, then returning the JObject.ToString() with no manipulation but it failed.  I will see if I can make your suggestion work though!  Thanks!

Comment: Great if u find the answer useful kindly upvote or accept

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` does not parse `multipart/form-data` body. I will parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it looks like that's what you've confused `multipart/form-data` with. Please refer to the proper RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578 on what does `multipart/form-data` look like.